# Introduce information to a hash in Perl

Tags: perl, hash

I've got this file:

```
313-9640000-9660000:19634:fwd   maker   gene    1978    7195    .       +       .       ID=maker-313-9640000-9660000%3A19634%3Afwd-augustus-gene-0.10;Name=maker-313-9640000-9660000%253A19634%253Afwd-augustus-gene-0.10
313-9640000-9660000:19634:fwd   maker   mRNA    1978    7195    .       +       .       ID=maker-313-9640000-9660000%3A19634%3Afwd-augustus-gene-0.10-mRNA-1;Name=maker-313-9640000-9660000%253A19634%253Afwd-augustus-gene-0.10-mRNA-1;Parent=maker-313-9640000-9660000%3A19634%3Afwd-augustus-gene-0.10
313-9640000-9660000:19634:fwd   maker   exon    1978    2207    0.48    +       .       Parent=maker-313-9640000-9660000%3A19634%3Afwd-augustus-gene-0.10-mRNA-1
313-9640000-9660000:19634:fwd   maker   exon    3081    3457    0.48    +       .       Parent=maker-313-9640000-9660000%3A19634%3Afwd-augustus-gene-0.10-mRNA-1
313-9640000-9660000:19634:fwd   maker   exon    3535    3700    0.48    +       .       Parent=maker-313-9640000-9660000%3A19634%3Afwd-augustus-gene-0.10-mRNA-1
313-9640000-9660000:19634:fwd   maker   exon    4247    4391    0.48    +       .       ID=maker-313-9640000-9660000%3A19634%3Afwd-augustus-gene-0.10-mRNA-1:exon:2;Parent=maker-313-9640000-9660000%3A19634%3Afwd-augustus-gene-0.10-mRNA-1
313-9640000-9660000:19634:fwd   maker   exon    6766    7195    0.48    +       .       Parent=maker-313-9640000-9660000%3A19634%3Afwd-augustus-gene-0.10-mRNA-1
313-9640000-9660000:19634:fwd   maker   CDS     3267    3457    .       +       0       ID=maker-313-9640000-9660000%3A19634%3Afwd-augustus-gene-0.10-mRNA-1:cds:0;Parent=maker-313-9640000-9660000%3A19634%3Afwd-augustus-gene-0.10-mRNA-1
313-9640000-9660000:19634:fwd   maker   CDS     3535    3700    .       +       .       Parent=maker-313-9640000-9660000%3A19634%3Afwd-augustus-gene-0.10-mRNA-1
313-9640000-9660000:19634:fwd   maker   CDS     4247    4391    .       +       .       ID=maker-313-9640000-9660000%3A19634%3Afwd-augustus-gene-0.10-mRNA-1:cds:2;Parent=maker-313-9640000-9660000%3A19634%3Afwd-augustus-gene-0.10-mRNA-1
313-9640000-9660000:19634:fwd   maker   CDS     6766    7106    .       +       .       ID=maker-313-9640000-9660000%3A19634%3Afwd-augustus-gene-0.10-mRNA-1:cds:3;Parent=maker-313-9640000-9660000%3A19634%3Afwd-augustus-gene-0.10-mRNA-1
```

The important part here is the column 3 (gene, mRNA...).

So, I'd like to make a hash, key=gene, mRNA... value=the whole line.

I've tried this:

```
%features = ();
while ($line = <>) {
  chomp;
  my @gff_data = split /\t+/;
  $features{$gff_data[2]} = @gff_data;
}
for my $key (sort keys %features) {
    print "$key = $features{$key}\n";
}
```

but does not work......

Comment: `$gff_data[2]` is not unique and it should be when using hash.

Comment: So, I cannot classify the lines that are genes, mRNA... together?

Comment: You cannot store all this information an a "typical" key => value hash where both key and value are string literals. Key has to be unique. You can store this information in a hash like this: key => (value1, value2, value3... valueN), so the value is a list instead of a string.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to group lines by column 3,

```
my %features;
while (<>) {
  chomp;
  my @gff_data = split /\t+/;
  push @{ $features{$gff_data[2]} }, \@gff_data;
}

use Data::Dumper;
print Dumper \%features;
```

Answer (score 1):

Are there ever any spaces embedded in the values of any of the fields? I assume not.

The values in column three aren't unique, so presumably you want an *array* of data lines for each different key?

If the current record is in `$_` then the value of the third column is in `(split)[2]`.

Something like this will do the trick.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Data::Dump;

open my $fh, '<', 'myfile.txt' or die $!;

my %data;
while (<$fh>) {
  chomp;
  push @{ $data{(split)[2]} }, $_;
}

dd \%data;
```

**output**

```
{
  CDS  => [
            "313-9640000-9660000:19634:fwd maker CDS   3267  3457  .   +   0   ID=maker-313-9640000-9660000%3A19634%3Afwd-augustus-gene-0.10-mRNA-1:cds:0;Parent=maker-313-9640000-9660000%3A19634%3Afwd-augustus-gene-0.10-mRNA-1",
            "313-9640000-9660000:19634:fwd maker CDS   3535  3700  .   +   .   Parent=maker-313-9640000-9660000%3A19634%3Afwd-augustus-gene-0.10-mRNA-1",
            "313-9640000-9660000:19634:fwd maker CDS   4247  4391  .   +   .   ID=maker-313-9640000-9660000%3A19634%3Afwd-augustus-gene-0.10-mRNA-1:cds:2;Parent=maker-313-9640000-9660000%3A19634%3Afwd-augustus-gene-0.10-mRNA-1",
            "313-9640000-9660000:19634:fwd maker CDS   6766  7106  .   +   .   ID=maker-313-9640000-9660000%3A19634%3Afwd-augustus-gene-0.10-mRNA-1:cds:3;Parent=maker-313-9640000-9660000%3A19634%3Afwd-augustus-gene-0.10-mRNA-1",
          ],
  exon => [
            "313-9640000-9660000:19634:fwd maker exon  1978  2207  0.48  +   .   Parent=maker-313-9640000-9660000%3A19634%3Afwd-augustus-gene-0.10-mRNA-1",
            "313-9640000-9660000:19634:fwd maker exon  3081  3457  0.48  +   .   Parent=maker-313-9640000-9660000%3A19634%3Afwd-augustus-gene-0.10-mRNA-1",
            "313-9640000-9660000:19634:fwd maker exon  3535  3700  0.48  +   .   Parent=maker-313-9640000-9660000%3A19634%3Afwd-augustus-gene-0.10-mRNA-1",
            "313-9640000-9660000:19634:fwd maker exon  4247  4391  0.48  +   .   ID=maker-313-9640000-9660000%3A19634%3Afwd-augustus-gene-0.10-mRNA-1:exon:2;Parent=maker-313-9640000-9660000%3A19634%3Afwd-augustus-gene-0.10-mRNA-1",
            "313-9640000-9660000:19634:fwd maker exon  6766  7195  0.48  +   .   Parent=maker-313-9640000-9660000%3A19634%3Afwd-augustus-gene-0.10-mRNA-1",
          ],
  gene => [
            "313-9640000-9660000:19634:fwd maker gene  1978  7195  .   +   .   ID=maker-313-9640000-9660000%3A19634%3Afwd-augustus-gene-0.10;Name=maker-313-9640000-9660000%253A19634%253Afwd-augustus-gene-0.10",
          ],
  mRNA => [
            "313-9640000-9660000:19634:fwd maker mRNA  1978  7195  .   +   .   ID=maker-313-9640000-9660000%3A19634%3Afwd-augustus-gene-0.10-mRNA-1;Name=maker-313-9640000-9660000%253A19634%253Afwd-augustus-gene-0.10-mRNA-1;Parent=maker-313-9640000-9660000%3A19634%3Afwd-augustus-gene-0.10",
          ],
}
```

Comment: hey, can you finally learn to write comment when down voting?

Comment: @mpapec: Are you talking to me?

Comment: how does it look like?

Comment: @mpapec: It looks like you're talking to me but there's no downvote and it's my own answer.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot take the 3rd field as your hash key, as the input(3rd field) has names mentioned multiple times, e.g, exon is 5 times, and a hash key is always unique. Try the below code, it's easy to understand too.

```
open (INPUT, 'input.txt') or die "Couldn't open file, $!";
my @data = <INPUT>;
my @finalData;

foreach(@data)
{
my @newData = split(/\s+/,$_);
push(@finalData,"$newData[2]","$_")
}

for(my $i=0;$i<scalar @finalData;$i++)
{
print "Key => $finalData[$i]\nValue => $finalData[$i+1]\n";
$i++;
}
```